# Recommendation for RDBMS for large table

Tags: mysql, oracle, postgresql

I have been asked for recommendation on the optimal RDBMS for a large amount of data. The largest table would contain 2TB of data. My own largest table is only 400GB (mysql, performs very well).

The individual rows are going to be short, no blobs/etc, just a lookup table.

Is PostgreSQL nowadays performing better than MySQL? Can I ask DBAs with tables in this order of magnitude for their experience? Oracle might be considered as well. The available hardware is probably a standard linux box with about 64G ram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with MySQL (InnoDB engine of course) if your table is partitioned. PostgreSQL partitioning implementation with master-child tables and trigger based partition selection looks somewhat complicated for me. On the other hand in Oracle to use partitions one have to use Enterprise Edition ($47500 for 2 cores!) with Partitioning option (another $11500 for 2 cores).
From experience we have similar sized tables in both Oracle and MySQL. Performance and management is OK with both of them.

Answer (score 5):

The size of the tables really doesn't matter all that much. It's all about how well indexed the tables are and how many people are using the database at once.

In my case I've got clients with billions of rows in a single table where the table size is about 1 TB and another 2 billion row table which has blobs.  These tables crank without performance issues at all.

In this case the server has 1TB of RAM, 80 cores, and is running Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2.  Granted not all that helpful if you want a *nix OS, but it gives you some ideas that most database platforms can handle just about everything.